# how to connect luis endpoint url with action fulfillment using rest api?

Tags: c#, bots, rest-client, azure-language-understanding

Hi I am working on LUIS in I created the one LUIS application in luis.ai in that I used the action fulfillments like getweather and getnews in one my intent  then after I published my luis application like this below here.

[image]

In my above screen shot there are two endpoint url’s first endpoint url  is used for to identifying the intents and entities of my application. The second endpoint url is used for to connect bot with luis to get the results from any application.

But my scenario is without using the bot I want to get the action fulfilments(getweather, gennews) results using REST API Client in any mobile application(windows or ios or android).

Can you  please give me the suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, unfortunately, you cannot use action fulfillments outside of Bot Framework or direct Slack integration.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a4bbcf0-dd05-4358-95d6-6d518e4789e6/action-fulfillment-not-working?forum=LUIS

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/LUIS-api/documentation/PublishingToABot

Comment: Thanks for sharing a valuable information regarding on this.